# How to solve prime power mathematical problem python

Tags: python, math, prime-factoring

So i have a mathematical problem about prime power.  A number x can be considered a prime power if x = p^k where p is a prime and k is a non-negative integer. For example, 81 is a prime power because 81 = 3^4. Now, form a sequence of numbers in the following way. Start by taking a random number.

1. If the number is a prime power, end the sequence.
2. If the number is not a prime power, minus that number with the biggest prime power that's not more than the number itself. Do it over and over again until a prime power is met, then stop.

For example, 34 is not a prime power. Hence we minus it with the highest prime power that's not more than it which is 32, hence 34-32=2. 2 is a prime power, so we stop. In this case, the length of the operation is 2 (because 34 -> 2).

Another example is 95. 95 isn't a prime power, so 95-89=6. 6 is also not a prime power, so we minus it again with the highest prime power, 6-5=1. 1 is a prime power (because 2^0 = 1), so we stop. In this case, the length of the operation is 3 (because 95 -> 6 -> 1).

Known that:

- 1 is the smallest initial number that can be formed with a length of
  1 operation.
- 6 is the smallest initial number that can be formed with
  a length of 2 operations.
- 95 is the smallest initial number that can
  be formed with a length of 3 operations.
- 360748 is the smallest
  initial number that can be formed with a length of 4 operations.

So i want to make an application using Python to find the smallest initial number that can be formed with a length of 5,6 and 7 operations.

Below is the syntax I've came up with. It is using looping to solve the problem. However, to find the smallest initial number that can be formed with a length of 4 or more operations, the program takes a very very long time to run. Is there any way i could improve my code to make the program to run much faster? I just want to focus on getting the number with 5,6 and 7 operations.

```
from sympy.ntheory import factorint
def pp(q): #to check whether it is a prime power
    fact=factorint(q)
    p=int(list(fact.keys())[0])
    n=int(list(fact.values())[0])
    if q!=p**n:
        return False
    else:
        return True

a=[1,6][-1]

b=a*2
d=1
while d!=0:
    c=b-a
    if pp(b)==False and pp(c)==True:
        for i in range(b-1,c-1,-1):
            if i==c:
                d=0
            elif pp(i)==True:
                b=i+a
                break
    elif pp(b)==False:
        for i in range(b-1,c-1,-1):
            if i==c:
                b=b+a+1
            elif pp(i)==True:
                b=i+a
                break
    elif pp(b)==True:
        b=b+a
b
```

I know it is a very long process. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I think you should ask this question over at [codereview.se]. But read their help page first to see if this question really fits!

Comment: Where are the known values taken from? Potentially the person providing those values might have tried to get to much larger values and solving this problem might be beyond code improvement (and maybe it really needs a lot of computational power to push to 5). This is not to discourage you but to be aware that this problem might just be very hard to solve with a direct coding approach.

Comment: Just trying numbers one by one certainly will be much too slow. Note that for the four given numbers, they are just the sequence `360748 - 360653 -> 95 - 89 -> 6 - 5 -> 1`, so `360748` is the first number that has a prime gap of exactly `95` for which the gap also doesn't contain any power of a prime.  For the next number, you need a primegap of at least `360748` also without intervening powers. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Numerical_results), your prime has to be at least  `17,051,707` to get such a gap.

Comment: So `17051707 - 1094422 + 360748` might be a candidate, or maybe one of the numbers around there, depending on your luck with prime powers in that region. Other tables with prime gaps will be useful (as wikipedia only lists the records). As you know this is an existing primegap, you only need to check for prime powers which should be faster than checking for primes. Just start with the sqrt of the lower bound, find primes and square those. If this leaves enough space, try with third powers etc. Just checking the squares of primes in the range shows there is no gap of at least 360748.